# jquery form validation script doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello there i have a problem calling jquery script to work. I have an `index.html` file. Where i include jquery like this: 
 `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` 
And my file with jquery script like this:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/error.handler.js"></script>`
Then when special button is clicked, AJAX function loads `regForm.html` file into body of  `index.html` there i have registration form like this:

`<form  name="regForm" id="regForm"action= "save_user.php"  method="post">
                ******
                <ul id ="inputForms">
                    <li id="l11"><input type = "text" id="login" name="login" size="15" maxlength="15" /></li>
                </ul>
                ******
<div id="regButContainer"> <input type="submit" id="regButton2" value="Register Now" name="submit"></div></form>`

I try to make verification of login input field with this script:

```
$(function(){
$( "#regForm" ).submit(function( event ) {

    var errors = false;

    if($('#login').value() == ""){
        alert("lLOGIN CANNOT BE EMPTY!");
        errors = true;
}
    if (errors==true) {

        return false;
    }


});});
```

But when submit button is clicked script is not working so it ends up triggering save_user.php file to work. When i use html's `onsubmit` function and use standard javascript function everything works. But there is fancy things i want to do with jquery so i switched to it and now i'm in front of a brick wall. Can anyone explain me why my script refuses to work?

Answer (score 0):

change

$('#login').value()

to

$('#login').val()

Comment: are you getting the alert?

Comment: if i was i would knew what to do

Comment: don't be snarky with me. i was just trying to help debug your problem.

Comment: i'm sorry if you was offended by my comment, i'm really appreciating all the help i can get

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your `$('#regForm).submit( )` function after the form is loaded by the AJAX.

Assuming you're using `$.load( )` to do this, it should look something similar to this:

```
$('#form_container').load('regForm.html', function() {
    $( "#regForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
        var errors = false;
        if($('#login').val() == ""){
            alert("lLOGIN CANNOT BE EMPTY!");
            errors = true;
        }
        if (errors==true) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

The reason for this is because the form isn't loaded at the time your add the submit event.

Comment: But why form loads fine when i use javascript instead of jquery?

Comment: Well, it doesn't look like it's an issue with the form loading so much as your custom submit action not working.  I'm thinking that the $('#regForm').submit( ) event isn't being taken into account because you're trying to add it before the form is loaded.

Comment: when i try to use `$("#regButton2").click(function` it's not working either

Comment: That's in line with what my answer should fix for you.  Have you tried placing all of your custom form events in the complete function as I demonstrated?

Comment: And you did change the `$('#login').value( )` to `$("#login').val( )`, right? You don't happen to have a link, do you?

Comment: i did =/ and there is no changes =(

Comment: It's hard to diagnose without testing it out myself. If you can create a jsFiddle or provide a link I'd be more than happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the event.preventDefault(); in any case you want to stop the form from submiting.
Also I believe that your problem is that you should have $('#login').val() instead of $('#login').value(). normally your script should work without preventDefault();

http://jsfiddle.net/cra5L/

```
$( "#regForm" ).submit(function( event ) {

    if($('#login').val() == ""){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("lLOGIN CANNOT BE EMPTY!");
        errors = true;        
    }
```

Comment: i thought about it, and it still like doesn't exist

Comment: yes, in my application it looks like script is being ignored, like it doesn't exist at all =/

Comment: Do you see anything in the console? firebug etc?

Comment: only warning about form containing password field

Comment: it douns confusing, could you create a complete jsfiddle of your code? Something is buggy there it seems.